# user's latitude longitude not getting proper

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get user's current lat and long from php with symfony I have use following code,but it not gives me proper result ,

```
$new_arr[] = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
        if ($new_arr) {
            $Latitude = $new_arr[0]['geoplugin_latitude'];
            $Longitude = $new_arr[0]['geoplugin_longitude'];
        }
```

can anybody help me to resolve it ?

Comment: What's wrong with the response? Are the latitude/longitude incorrect? Is there a Syntax Error?

Comment: The API isn't 100% accurate, for some addresses it might just provide a country-code, and not anything more specific, such as region or city. If you don't have that information, you won't know the lat/long either. For my IP, it just shows the country, but nothing more.

Comment: using that particular website to get my ip and location suggests that I am in `el segundo` which is in California.... I'm in the UK so perhaps use a more reliable source

Answer (score 0):

Considering you don't need a Proxy here a piece of code I used for a project:

```
function getIP()
{
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   return ($ip == "::1") ? "" : $ip;
}

$location = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/xml/'.getIP(), false));

$longitude = $location->Longitude;
$latitude = $location->Latitude;
```

With a proxy:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'ASK YOUR SYSADMIN', "request_fulluri" => true));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

function getIP()
{
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  return ($ip == "::1") ? "" : $ip;
}

$location = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://freegeoip.net/xml/'.getIP(), false, $context));

$longitude = $location->Longitude;
$latitude - $location->Latitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using doesn't give exact output so I would suggest you to use `GeoIP` Library.

- Create a folder on your server.
- Download the files given at following links

Here are the links to download all the files:

- Download [geoip.inc](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoip.inc)
- Download [geoipregionvars.php](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoipregionvars.php)
- Download [geoipcity.inc](http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php-20120410/geoipcity.inc)
- Download [GeoLiteCity.dat](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz)

Please all these files in a folder and rename `GeoLiteCity.dat.gz` to `GeoLiteCity.dat`

```
// I am assuming that folder name is geoip and then include all files
include ("geoip/geoipcity.inc");

include ("geoip/geoipregionvars.php");

$giCity = geoip_open("geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$record = geoip_record_by_addr($giCity, $ip);

echo "Getting Country and City detail by IP Address <br /><br />";
echo "IP: " . $ip . "<br /><br />";

// this array will give you all the details like address, city, state etc.
print_r($record);
```

All the best!